# Intermittently failing PPTP VPN connections

Tags: vpn, rras, pptp

I'm two weeks in as the System Administrator at a midsize manufacturing company with executives and sales staff who make heavy use of remote access.  From almost the day I arrived, I started getting complains about VPN performance problems.  Here's our setup:  Our gateway is an Astaro appliance that is configured with DNAT rules that forward PPTP and GRE traffic to an internal server we'll call COMPANY-VPN01.  COMPANY-VPN01 is a Windows Server 2003 box configured with RRAS.  Our client computers (mostly XP, but some Vista and 7) have Windows PPTP VPN connections set up to point to vpn.company.com, which resolves to the public IP of the Astaro box's external interface.

Here's the really strange part:  **every** time users connect to the VPN connection, it appears to work.  On the client machine, the VPN connection shows "connected" (and their ipconfig shows a PPP adapter with a DHCP-issued internal IP address), and I can see their connection on COMPANY-VPN01 as well).  However, more than half the time, these connections are no good -- users can't access **any** internal resources.  Since I've experienced this myself, I've tested some of the obvious things -- tried using FQDNs of internal resources instead of NetBIOS names, tried using IP addresses, tried pinging internal resources by name and IP address.  **Nothing** goes through.  But if I disconnect and reconnect the VPN connection a few times, I'll eventually get a connection that works *flawlessly* -- and will continue to work flawlessly, no matter how long I leave it connected.  So, whatever the problem is, it's a) intermittent and b) occurs when the VPN connection is being set up -- because if you get a "good" connection, it remains good.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on here, or suggestions for things we might troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I shouldn't just leave this unanswered forever when I have in fact solved the problem.

When I was hired, I was told that the LAN was "running out of scope". The network had a 24-bit subnet mask and uses DHCP for client addressing. The DHCP server wasn't set to check DNS before handing out addresses. DNS wasn't set to scavenge old records. RRAS was set to get addresses for VPN clients from DHCP, and by default it grabs blocks of 10. So it would grab blocks of 10 and start handing them out to clients, but as our address space ran out, some of them were "good" and some were already registered to other clients in DNS. I shortened the subnet mask to 22-bit and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion: Set up another RRAS server and direct the incoming VPN conections to this new server. If the problem persists then you'll have ruled out the server as the problem and can focus on the upstream devices, most likely the Astaro appliance, as the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I was hired, I was told that the LAN was "running out of scope". The network had a 24-bit subnet mask and uses DHCP for client. The DHCP server wasn't set to check DNS before handing out addresses. DNS wasn't set to scavenge old records. DHCP was set to get addresses from DHCP, and by default it grabs blocks of 10. So it would grab blocks of 10 and start handing them out to clients, but as our address space ran out, some of them were "good" and some were already registered to other clients in DNS. I shortened the subnet mask to 22-bit and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the appliance is the problem here, just a hunch.

Try firmware upgrade. Contact Astaro about this issue.

Try DMZ to the COMPANY-VPN01 server instead of DNAT rules.

And/or try plugging your internet directly into a 2nd NIC on the vpn server, and use RRAS Basic Firewall + NAT, and change your DHCP so new default gateway is that server.

OR.. you could code either a simple batch script, or pretty simple c# app to automatically redial the vpn endpoint if ping fails after x times, and ship a copy to all laptops (.msi?).

Answer (score 0):

It could be down to [PPTP Passthrough](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/07/28/pptp-passthrough/) not being supported or not working correctly on your outbound router. You also might want to read [Multiple VPN Connections – Why It Isn’t Possible](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/08/09/multiple-vpn-connections/) which explains why this happens and ways around it. It's a good read!